# How to stop a WPF Listbox from scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollviewer

I want my `ListBox` to never scroll.   It's easy to just hide/disable the scrollbars, but mousewheel/arrow keys still cause a scroll when the items in the `ListBox` exceed its boundaries.  There HAS to be some way to tell the `ListBox` that it just can't ever scroll....right?

Comment: do you want the selected item to still be highlighted, but the highlight goes out of view and the items remain static?

Comment: delete the scroll viewer from the template

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This sounds like very bizarre functionality.

Comment: Why do you want to make that statement?  This sounds like a very unimaginative proclamation ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to delete the `ScrollViewer` scroll bar from the `ListBox` `Template` property.  See if that works.

Comment: This answer is correct: Editing the ListBox template and removing the ScrollViewer from it will actually accomplish what was requested. But I too am puzzled about why you would ever want to do this in the first place.

Comment: I need to be able to detect a certain condition in which the Listbox cannot scroll, it's not really bizarre.  It is synced with a rendered component and if that component is currently not allowed to scroll, either can this listbox.